# Alert if logoff if certain git repos have unpushed changes

Tags: linux, git

Any way to alert if I try to logoff (or lock) if certain git repos have unpushed changes?

Comment: The former should be doable by  a simple script that interfaces the Windows API (yuck) and a GIT client (ok). Now, apps can tell when they're being shut down. I don't think they can delay the locking process, but maaybe anyone is (or was) willing to write a lock screen widget.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I use Linux.

Comment: You mean logging off from your window manager? If so, which one are you using?

Comment: MATE is my window manager, I use Linux Mint.

Comment: Currently your question is lacking a lot of detail on what is relevant. What Distro are you using? What WM? How good are you at scripting? What have you tried? All of that should be in your question. Maybe checkout the [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) help topic.

Comment: In my desktop manager (Plasma/KDE) I can hook to "notifications" and have these display messages, make noises, or execute scripts. There is a `logout` notification, it would be a snap to add a script to `git push` things. I don't know Mate, but I'll assume it has the same kind functionalities, otherwise you can perhaps hook on D-Bus notifications.